# Scaling a figure to fit in a pdf page using reportlab, and svglib

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, reportlab, svgutils

I stumbled on this code to generate a PDF with a plot in it without saving the plot as a file.

I am now trying to scale the svg before adding it to the PDF so it fits the page (without changing the figsize argument through matplotlib).

```
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import LETTER
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from io import BytesIO

from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg

def one_page_pdf(file_name, figs, text="Default"):
    canvas = Canvas(filename=file_name, pagesize=(LETTER[1], LETTER[0]))
    img_data = BytesIO()
    figs.savefig(img_data, format="svg")
    # figs.set_size_inches(6, 6)
    img_data.seek(0)

    drawing = svg2rlg(img_data)
    renderPDF.draw(drawing, canvas, 10, 100)
    canvas.drawString(10, 50, text)
    canvas.showPage()
    canvas.save()
```

How can I do it properly?

I tried changing the size of the svg using svgutils but this didn't go well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this being rather a late reply, I just happened to find this post today while looking for a solution myself.

I was trying to do exactly this, and getting myself tied in all kinds of knots trying to scale an SVG image (it's not at all straightforward).

Then I found that the reportlab drawing has a renderScale property (which I cannot find a mention of in the docs).

So for your example above I think this would scale it by half:

```
drawing.renderScale = 0.5
```

This has worked nicely in my project.